# Need help on writing sql query

Tags: sql

I need a help writing a sql query.  Assume the following tables as input

Table #1: `hostname`

```
host_id     host_name
1          420000-PC001
2          420000-PC002
```

Table #2: `asset_id`

```
asset_id    asset_type  asset_serialno  host_id
1            cpu          CPU10001        1
2            cpu          CPU10002        2
3            monitor      MON10001        1
4            monitor      MON10002       NULL
5            printer      PRN10001        2
```

Relationship between two tables is on the `host_id` column.

I want the output table in the following format

```
host_name      cpu_serialno   monitor_serialno   printer_serialno
420000-PC001    CPU10001        MON10001           NULL
420000-PC002    CPU10002        NULL               PRN10001
```

Please help me in writing this sql query... I wrote a query but I am unable to display the null values...

Comment: Please add the query you already tried. That said, I think you should first read on the basics of SQL and I am sure you will be able to solve it yourself.

Comment: select h.host_name, cpu.asset_serialno, mon.asset_serialno, prn.asset_serialno from hostname h, (select * from asset_id where asset_type='cpu') as cpu, (select * from asset_id where asset_type='monitor') as mon, (select * from asset_id where asset_type='printer') as prn where h.host_id = cpu.host_id or h.host_id = mon.host_id or h.host_id = prn.host_id

Comment: iam unable to get it work...

Answer (score 0):

Do a left join for each product type:

```
select host_name , cpu_serialno, monitor_serialno, printer_serialno
from hostname
  left join (select asset_id, asset_serialno  as cpu_serialno
             from asset_id
             where asset_type = 'cpu') cpu_table
     ON hostname.host_id = cpu_table.hostname
  left join (select asset_id, asset_serialno  as monitor_serialno
             from asset_id
             where asset_type = 'monitor') monitor_table
     ON hostname.host_id = monitor_table.hostname
  left join (select asset_id, asset_serialno  as printer_serialno
             from asset_id
            where asset_type = 'printer') printer_table
     ON hostname.host_id = printer_table.hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LEFT JOINS` with sub-queries, something like that:

```
SELECT host_name, 
       cpu_serialno, 
       monitor_serialno, 
       printer_serialno
FROM hostname AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  asset_id, 
                   asset_serialno AS cpu_serialno
             FROM  asset_id
             WHERE asset_type = 'cpu') t2
ON t1.host_id = t2.hostname
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  asset_id, 
                   asset_serialno  AS monitor_serialno
             FROM  asset_id
             WHERE asset_type = 'monitor') t3
ON t1.host_id = t3.hostname
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  asset_id, 
                   asset_serialno  AS printer_serialno
             FROM  asset_id
             WHERE asset_type = 'printer') t4
ON t1.host_id = t4.hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative can be following SELECT statement

```
select
HOST_NAME,
max(cpu_serialno) cpu_serialno,
max(monitor_serialno) monitor_serialno,
max(printer_serialno) printer_serialno
from (
select 
    h.host_name,
    cpu_serialno = case when asset_type = 'cpu' then asset_serialno else null end,
    monitor_serialno = case when asset_type = 'monitor' then asset_serialno else null end,
    printer_serialno = case when asset_type = 'printer' then asset_serialno else null end
from hostname h
inner join asset_id a on h.host_id = a.host_id
) t
group by host_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone replied my query. Based your suggestions i created a query as follows which solved my problem

```
select h.host_name, cpu.asset_serialno, mon.asset_serialno, prn.asset_serialno from hostname h 
left join (select * from asset_id where asset_type='cpu') cpu on h.host_id = cpu.host_id 
left join (select * from asset_id where asset_type='monitor') mon on h.host_id = mon.host_id 
left join (select * from asset_id where asset_type='printer') prn on h.host_id = prn.host_id
```